# Adding workflow to files

Tags: 7, media, workflows

I'm working on a site that should let users to publish files (images), but I would to add a kind of workflow for these files.
Is there a way? I was thinking to use private/public files, in this way:

- by default files are stored in "private" mode (so only certain users can see them)
- create a module that simulates a workflow that "publish" a file, moving it to the "public" mode

Could be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a content type called images, remove all the clutter and just add an image field. Since your images are now nodes, you can use any workflow module that you generally use. (Note you will have a overhead of one node for every image you upload)

If you don't want to follow the above approach then you can consider using [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module along with the the private folder options in image field settings.

Comment: This is a good way, but even if the node is not published, the file upload on sites/default/files is always available, so the best way could be to move files from private to public

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how you will tie this into like user roles or what your business logic is.

Here are some ideas / resources:

- [MediaMover](http://www.drupal.org/project/mediamover) module -- can add abitrary workflows to files. The examples are transcoding files, but its likely it could attach remove files to a public/privately made node for content viewing or sharing.
- [File Entity](http://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) for D7, files are entities in D7.... woo!
- [Relation ACL](http://drupal.org/sandbox/deviantintegral/1863172), [Relation](http://www.drupal.org/project/relation) is a module to add "relations" to entities. Relation ACL creates access logic to the given entity.
- [Encrypted Stream Wrapper](http://drupal.org/sandbox/juankvillegas/1867708) or [Encrypted Local Stream Wrapper](http://drupal.org/sandbox/ChuckZ/1834922), setups up a private filesystem URI and uploads files to that location. Allowed users can stream a de-crypted copy of the file to the enduser, files are stored encrypted on the filesystem.
- [Private Dynamic File Stream](http://drupal.org/project/private_dynamic_stream), store file entities of a certain type in a private filesytem and stream them as neccesary.

From your brief question I think you want to look at file_entity and either media mover or relation_acl.